# Liquibase: Add a column to a table and fill the new column for each existing row with a unique value

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I´m looking for solution for the following problem:

I have a table A and I want to add a column - simple varchar for UUID strings => easy.

The problem is, that I need a unique UUID in the existing rows: I have to - somehow - go through all rows and add a generated UUID.

What I tried so far is:

```
<addColumn tableName="mhds_task">
  <column name="execution_key" type="varchar(255)" valueComputed="(SELECT md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text)::uuid)"/>
</addColumn>
```

But this will give me the same value in each row - I assume liquibase is computing the value once per column?

I´ve researched for 2 hours now - I cannot believe that I´m the only one who wants to achieve something like this ;)

Any ideas or hints?

Best regards
Marius

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried to find a solution for this issue back in a day, but had no luck.
So I had to write separate changeSets:

1. To simply add a column with no values;
2. To fill the column with generated data as such:

   ```
   <changeSet id="foo" author="bar">
      <update tableName="mhds_task">
           <column name="execution_key" 
           valueComputed="(SELECT md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text)::uuid)"/>
       </update>
    </changeSet>
   ```

Comment: how would i update a recently created column from the csv file